# setup email server for self-register email confirmation

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, mail-server

I have a problem setup email server for self-register confirmation step.

```
my email settings :
 from_address= "wso2@lepgo.online"
 username= "wso2@lepgo.online"
 password= "thisisnotmytherealpassword"
 hostname= "mail.lepgo.online"
 port= 465
 enable_start_tls= true
 enable_authentication= true
```

and sure about about this server settings that it isa correct

this what I get

```
[2023-03-06 19:28:57,376] [ee855329-2e3f-4ed1-8258-bcc9ecaa3602] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter} - Exception occurred when sending email to omarehabsal@gmail.com. Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 578; timeout -1 com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 578; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter$EmailSender.run(EmailEventAdapter.java:367)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:557)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:359)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2175)
        ... 12 more
```

I expect to be able to confirm my users accounts by email but could not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Firewall is not allowing the connection to `smtp.gmail.com, 578`. Check your firewall rules and allow outgoing conections to the SMTP server.